# Save to array in for loop, with steps - Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Okay, this is a bit tricky to explain, but I have a long .txt file with data (only one column). It could look like this:

```
data=[18
32
50
3
19
31
48
2
18
33
51
4]
```

Now, every fourth value (e.g. 18, 19, 18) represents the same physical quantity, just from different measurements. Now, I want Matlab to take every fourth value and put it into an array `X=[18 19 18]`, and like wise for the other quantities.

My solution so far looks like this:

```
for i=1:3;
     for j=1:4:12;
        X(i)=data(j);
     end
end
```

... in this example, because there are three of each quantity (therefore `i=1:3`), and there are 12 datapoints in total (therefore `j=1:4:12`, in steps of 4). `data` is simply the loaded list of datapoints (this works fine, I can test it in command window - e.g. `data(2)=32`).

My problem, doing this, is, that my array turns out like `X=[18 18 18]` - i.e. only the last iteration is put into the array

Of course, in the end, I would like to do it for all points; saving the 2nd, 6th, and 10th datapoint into `Y` and so on. But this is simply having more `for`-loops I guess.

I hope this question makes sense. I guess it is an easy problem to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do?

```
>> X = data(1:4:end)
X =

   18
   19
   18

>> Y = data(2:4:end)
Y =

   32
   31
   33
```

Comment: I simply wasn't aware of the possibility of doing steps like this. Thanks! I guess this is the most simple solution out there. Thanks! :)

Comment: @NielsMøller I would recommend using `reshape` in your case rather than this, see the other two solutions

Comment: I guess both works pretty fine for my purpose. I'll see what turns out to be the most powerfull in my actual data analysis, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You can reshape the data and then either split it up into different variables or just know that each column is a different variable (I'm now assuming each measurement occurs the same number of times i.e. `length(data)` is a multiple of `4`)

```
data = reshape(data, 4, []).';
```

So now if you want

```
X = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,2);
%// etc...
```

But also you could just leave it as `data` all in one variable since calling `data(:,1)` is hardly more hassle than `X`.

---

Now, you should **NOT** use `for`-loops for this, but I'm gong to address what's wrong with your loops and how to solve this using loops purely as an explanation of the logic. You have a nested loop:

```
for i=1:3;
     for j=1:4:12;
        X(i)=data(j);
     end
end
```

Now what you were hoping was that `i` and `j` would each move one iteration forward together. So when `i==1` then `j==1`, when `i==2` then `j==5` etc but this is not what happens at all. To best understand what's going on I suggest you print out the variables at each iteration:

```
disp(sprintf('i:  \tj:'));
for i=1:3;
     for j=1:4:12;
        disp(sprintf('   %d\t   %d',i,j));
     end
end
```

This prints out

```
i:      j:
   1       1
   1       5
   1       9
   2       1
   2       5
   2       9
   3       1
   3       5
   3       9
```

What you wanted was

```
disp(sprintf('i:  \tj:'));
for i=1:3;
     disp(sprintf('   %d\t   %d',i,4*i-3));
end
```

which outputs:

```
i:      j:
   1       1
   2       5
   3       9
```

applied to your problem:

```
%// preallocation!
X = zeros(size(data,1)/4, 1)
for i=1:3
    X(i)=data(i*4 - 3);
end
```

Or alternatively you can keep a separate count of either `i` or `j`:

```
%// preallocation!
X = zeros(size(data,1)/4, 1)
i = 1;
for j=1:4:end;
    X(i)=data(j);
    i = i+1;
end
```

Comment: LOL for the 2nd time :) you were faster +1

Comment: Actually last time you were ;) +1 for you too!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what was wrong! I see... I was hoping they jumped together... of course they don't. +1 :)

Comment: Anyways i deleted mine to avoid same answers repeating twice.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness your own solution should have read

```
 i = 0;
 for j=1:4:12;
    i = i+1;
    X(i)=data(j);
 end
```

Of course am304's answer is a better way of doing it.